# How to remove everything fron the superView and not just the last item?

Tags: iphone, uiview

In my app i had to draw certain checkboxes at a same time and i used a single function to add all of them. Now when a user clicks one of them all of those checkboxes should get removed from the superview and currently its just removing the last one. Also i have issue to recognize those checkboxes like which one is clicked. i know it should be done through Tag property but don't know how exactly it should be implemented.
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all subviews

```
int numberOfSubviews = [[yourView subviews] count];

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfSubviews-1;i++
    {
      [[youView subviews]objectAtIndex:i]removeFromSuperView];
    }
```

//this will leave check box that you added at last.... for first one to remain loop from `1 to numberOfSubview`s....

Using tag property...
when you are creating checkbox objects use

```
checkBoxObject.tag = i;
```

//I am considering i as looop count which you are using in a loop 
to add checkboxes.

then whenever you need a object of `checkbox`

```
[yourViewonwhichYouAddedCheckBox viewWithTag:<your tag >];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For identifying a "checkbox" or better said any view within an action-method:

```
- (void)someActionHandler:(id)sender
{
  UIView *actionOriginView = (UIView *)sender;
  NSLog(@"this action came from view:%d", actionOriginView.tag);
}
```

For assigning the tag, you may use the IB or within your code, while instantiating;

```
UIView *myFunkyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
myFunkyView.tag = 1337;
```

For removing a bunch of views from your superview - lets assume their tag is set to 10 - 15;

```
for (int i=10;i <= 15;i++)
{
  UIView *childView = [superview viewWithTag:i];
  [childView removeFromSuperview];
}
```